# como implementar o método jaccknife no caso em que se retiram dois termos(em R)

Tags: r, variância, estatística-bootstrap

Criei o seguinte código para calcular a variância através do método jackknife.
 Porém, ao invés de retirar um termo por vez, agora preciso retirar de 2 em 2.
 sei que é algo básico, mas não consegui pensar em como fazer isso, alguém poderia me dar alguma ideia?

```
A<- numeric(1000)


var1<- numeric(1000)

x<- data.frame(numeric(9))

amostra<- rnorm(10,100,10) #gerando amostra

for(i in 1:10){

x[i]<-c(amostra[-i]) #tirando um termo da amostra

}

var2<- numeric(10) #calculando as variancias dos vetores n-1

for(i in 1:10){

  var2[i]<- var(x[,i])
}

Tn<- sum(var2) #soma das variancias de 3 termos

var1[j] <- var(amostra)# variancia da amstra de tamanho n


A[j]<-10*var1[j]-((9/10)*Tn) #  variancia Jackknife
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te ajudar a achar `var2` e `Tn`. A partir daí eu não entendi o que você fez.

```
#Todas as combinações de índices de 10 elementos tomados 8 a 8.
idx <- t(combn(10, 8))
#Todas as sub-amostras de 8 elementos
x <- apply(idx, 2, function(x){amostra[x]})
#Variancia de cada sub-amostra
var2 <- apply(x, 1, var)
# soma das variancias
Tn <- sum(var2)
```

Confira tudo, porque não ficou claro para mim qual deveria ser o conteúdo de `x`.

Comment: Ajudou muito, a partir dai eu consigo desenvolver o resto! Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Tentei o seguinte:

Como você quer retirar de dois em dois, o dataframe deverá ter 8 linhas, caso contrário a realocação dos dados será incompatível, pois está se tirando 2 valores por vez:

```
x<- data.frame(numeric(8))

amostra<- rnorm(10,100,10) #gerando amostra

amostra

[1] 108.27618  99.33371 122.50547 105.59071  89.95836 108.99908 101.51803  96.98692 100.51190 102.91556

for(i in 1:8){
  x[i]<- c(amostra[-c(i,i+1)]) # retira dois termos por iteração
}

x

numeric.8.        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8
1  122.50547 108.27618 108.27618 108.27618 108.27618 108.27618 108.27618 108.27618
2  105.59071 105.59071  99.33371  99.33371  99.33371  99.33371  99.33371  99.33371
3   89.95836  89.95836  89.95836 122.50547 122.50547 122.50547 122.50547 122.50547
4  108.99908 108.99908 108.99908 108.99908 105.59071 105.59071 105.59071 105.59071
5  101.51803 101.51803 101.51803 101.51803 101.51803  89.95836  89.95836  89.95836
6   96.98692  96.98692  96.98692  96.98692  96.98692  96.98692 108.99908 108.99908
7  100.51190 100.51190 100.51190 100.51190 100.51190 100.51190 100.51190 101.51803
8  102.91556 102.91556 102.91556 102.91556 102.91556 102.91556 102.91556 102.91556
```